# How to use CUTThread in CUDA

Tags: gpu, cuda

I am trying to run my own multi-gpu example, and I am following the NVIDIA's example. However, I cannot find where CUTThread is defined and then the compiler says:

```
error: ‘CUTThread’ was not declared in this scope
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is 'dont use cutThread at all'. It comes from the SDK, not the toolkit, and it not intended for general use - NVIDIA don't document any of these function, nor do they guarantee that they either work, or won't change in definition or function from release to release. If you are interested in multiGPU computing, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7046013/multiple-gpus-in-cuda-3-2-and-issues-with-cuda-4-0/7050162#7050162) to a very recent Stackoverflow question.

Comment: I am using OpenMP threads. And it seems to work properly. Not very well detailed the multi gpu in CUDA...